# CDN / babel not letting me run html by rendering it to div element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

**HTML**
*I import the CDN links and babel from NodeJS website*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!--CDN links-->
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <!--Babbel script tag-->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
```

*I create a div for the code*

```
    <!--React div-->
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--JS Script Tags-->
```

*JS script tag with babble set as type*

```
<script src="index.js" type="text/babel"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**
*I render the code using the dom to the element id of the div*

```
    ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello world</h1>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: problem is here `<script src="index.js" type="text/babble"></script>` it should be `babel` not `babble`

Comment: Did you mean `type="text/babel"`?

Comment: Thank you, sorry I misspelled it while typing it back up, but I did spell it correctly in my native environment and it's not working

Answer (score 0):

seems to be working fine, however it has warnings, such as use `createRoot` warnings, which is asking to use it.

```js
ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello world</h1>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!--CDN links-->
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script
      crossorigin
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <!--Babbel script tag-->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>


    <!--React div-->
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--JS Script Tags-->

<script src="index.js" type="text/babel"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

which can be solved by:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(app);
```